# Using addSnapshotListener with WhereArrayContains Firebase

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database the looks as following:

[image]

Inside "Chats", there are documents with name that is built from combination of 2 user ID's. Inside this document there is field called "Name" which is equal to that document name.

Im trying to addSnapshotListener to as follows:

```
public void getRooms(EventListener<QuerySnapshot> listener) {
    db.collection( "Chats" ).
            whereArrayContains( "Name", auth.getUid()).addSnapshotListener( listener );

}
```

What I wanted this code to do is to find all documents that inside their field "Name", the string contains the userID somewhere inside the string.

For example if there is a document called: `abcdegf` and the `auth.getUid() = abcd` I want it to find the document.
Or if the document called `egfabcd` I still want it to find it.

For some reason, it does not find any document even that I know there is a document that fits the query.

Is there anything that im doing wrong with `whereArrayContains`?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `whereArrayContains` operation is only valid on fields that are an **array** of values. Your `Name` field seems to contain a single string value, so `whereArrayContains` is not going to work on that field.

There is no operation in Firestore to check if a certain string field **contains** a value. The closest equivalent is that you can check if a certain field **starts with** a specific value.

If you need a real **contains** type operation, you'll have to use another/additional database for the search. For example, see the Firestore documentation on [using an external full-text search engine](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search).

But in this case, why don't you simple store the UIDs in an array field, instead of concatenating them into a single string?